# Two divs of 50%

Tags: html, css, width

I'm doing a HTML newsletter and i want two divs who take 50% of the page, one on the left and one on the right.

But the problem is that I tried with floats and tabs but no one is doing the job.

Do you have propostitions? Thank's <3

There's my code :)

```
#yellow {
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: rgb(214, 196, 0);
        order: 2;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #yellowL {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        margin: auto;
        order: 1;
    }

    #yellowR {
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        width: 50%;
        margin: auto;
        order: 2;
    }
```

and my HTML :)

```
<body id="NewsletterPRONA">
<div id="news">
    <h1>News</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus dictum, urna nec vulputate molestie, neque leo ultricies mi, ut dignissim magna magna vitae ex. Nunc eu massa purus. Vivamus velit lacus, vulputate a neque ut, faucibus tincidunt elit. Sed volutpat, nunc quis vulputate sagittis, ipsum metus elementum enim, sed ornare velit elit ac nibh.</p>
</div>
<div id="yellow">
    <h1 id="h1v2">Geschäftsverlauf / Déroulement des affaires</h1>
    <div id="yellowL">
        <h1 id="h1v2">Offerten</h1>
        <p>

        </p>
        <h1 id="h1v2">Projekte</h1>
        <p>

        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="yellowR">
        <h1 id="h1v2">Offres</h1>
        <h2>Bruit</h2>
        <p>

        </p>
        <h2>Sols</h2>
        <p>

        </p>
        <h2>Déchets</h2>
        <p>

        </p>
        <h2>EIE</h2>
        <p>

        </p>
        <h2>Physique et acoustique du bâtiment</h2>
        <p>

        </p>
        <h1 id="h1v2">Projets</h1>
        <h2>Bruit</h2>
        <p>

        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/N9mzE/1/

Comment: Thank's lordkain but it doesn't work with mines, I applied but it stays in column and not in row..

Comment: Try pull-right and pull-left...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tcL3sf6L/)

Change the CSS:

```
#yellow {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgb(214, 196, 0);
        order: 2;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #yellowL {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        margin: auto;
        order: 1;
    }

    #yellowR {
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        width: 50%;
        margin: auto;
        order: 2;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks it works <3 
But it's over the "personnel" subject, how to do it right?

Comment: It goes over the <h1>Personal / Personnel</h1> post, so what can I do to solve it?

Comment: if your <h1> string goes long then it will automatically wrap the text. Nothing to worry...

Comment: But it goes above https://jsfiddle.net/v1ktxL36/4/#&togetherjs=dMjuryFAOl

Answer (score 0):

Applying `float:left` to both div will do

**Html**

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box{
    margin:0;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Half of the page means? Vertically or Horizontally?

Comment: Horizonzaly, like float right and left with 50% of width but doesn't works

Comment: I don't understand the previous comment says you want row and here you say Horizontally. If you want the div to stay side by side then the answer will work. Try reducing the width a little bit.because if width is 50% and you set padding then the right side will go down

Comment: Use the display:inline-block; instead of the float then

Comment: float:left is also working. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N9mzE/1215/)

Comment: It's solved ;)

But now the text goes above above other content and I dont want it..

https://jsfiddle.net/v1ktxL36/4/#&togetherjs=dMjuryFAOl

Answer (score 0):

In newsletters the best solution is use a table.
Not a great solution, but the most cross compatible